# Quick array conversion from Java to C++

Tags: java, c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, porting

How would I use something like:

```
int array[][] = {{0,0,0},{1,0,0}};
```

...which is Java code in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
int array[2][3] = {{0,0,0},{1,0,0}};
```

Or this, because the first dimension is optional:

```
int array[][3] = {{0,0,0},{1,0,0}};
```

And by the way, in Java the idiomatic way to declare the same array is this:

```
int[][] array = {{0,0,0},{1,0,0}}; // [][] goes before the variable name
```

Comment: I'll make your answer the accepted one as it has more information. Thanks to both :)

Answer (score 3):

You would do it like so:

```
int array[][3] = {{0,0,0},{1,0,0}};
```

Only the first dimension may be omitted.